# 9 person randomly enter 3 different rooms

Tags: probability

9 person randomly enter 3 different rooms. What is the probability that

a)the first room has 3 person?

b)every room has 3 person?

c)the first room has n person, second room has 3 persons, third room 2 persons?

What i want to know is that which probability techniques i need to use when dealing with this type of questions, i have only learnt few techniques like combination and permutation only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"$9$ persons randomly enter $3$ different rooms" will be normally interpreted as
"$9$ persons randomly choose (uniformly and indipendently) the room to enter among $3$ different (distinguishable) rooms available".
In this case we consider to have $3^9$ equi-probable results given by the $9$-tuple individuating the choice of every
person. The *persons are distinguished* by assigning their position in the $9$-tuple, practically like as if they are taking
the choice one after the other.
This is equivalent to the scheme of throwing $9$ (undistinguishable) balls into $3$ (distinguishable) bins.

We can see that each possible $9$-tuple corresponds to a term of the expansion of the multinomial
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left( {r_{\,1}  + r_{\,2}  + r_{\,3} } \right)^{\,9}  =   \cr 
  &  =  \cdots  + r_{j_{\,1} } \,r_{j_{\,2} } \,r_{j_{\,3} } \, \cdots r_{j_{\,8} } \,r_{j_{\,9} } \,
 +  \cdots \quad \left| {\;j_{\,k}  \in \left\{ {1,2,3} \right\}} \right. =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{k_{\,1}  + k_{\,2}  + k_{\,3} \; = \,9}
   {\;\left( \matrix{  9 \cr k_{\,1} ,k_{\,2} ,k_{\,3}  \cr}  \right)r_{\,1} ^{\,k_{\,1} } r_{\,2} ^{\,k_{\,2} } r_{\,3} ^{\,k_{\,3} } }  \cr} 
$$
and the multinomial coefficient gives the number of ways to have the same occupancy hystogram : $k_1$ persons in room $1$, etc.

So the answer to question a) is 
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{k_{\,2}  + k_{\,3} \; = \,6} {\;\left( \matrix{  9 \cr   3,k_{\,2} ,k_{\,3}  \cr}  \right)}
  = \sum\limits_{k_{\,2}  + k_{\,3} \; = \,6} {\;{{9!} \over {3!k_{\,2} !k_{\,3} !}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( \matrix{  9 \hfill \cr   3 \hfill \cr}  \right)\sum\limits_k
 {\;\left( \matrix{  6 \hfill \cr   k \hfill \cr}  \right)}
  = \left( \matrix{  9 \hfill \cr   3 \hfill \cr}  \right)2^{\,6}  \cr} 
$$
which has an obvious interpretation as
(No of ways to choose the three occupants of 1st room) * (No. of ways the remaining $6$ people can choose $2$ rooms).

Then it is clear how to go for the other questions (re @abc..' answer).

Instead, the case of *undistinguished persons* is normally rendered as
"$9$ persons are randomly assigned to $3$ different rooms".
This problem is related to the [Compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29)
 of $9$ into $3$ parts, or equivalently with [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) scheme.

Here each triple $(n_1,n_2,n_3)$
$$
\left( {n_{\,1} ,n_{\,2} ,n_{\,3} } \right)\quad \left| \matrix{
  \;0 \le n_{\,k}  \le 9 \hfill \cr 
  \;n_{\,1}  + n_{\,2}  + n_{\,3}  = 9 \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
is considered equi-probable.
There are 
$$
\binom{9+3-1}{3-1} = \binom{11}{2} = 110
$$
possible accomodations (with empty rooms included), of which 
$$
\binom{6+2-1}{2-1} = 7
$$
will have $3$ persons in the first room.

Comment: If the people are distinguishable, then it's not stars and bars. If the people are identical, then the stars and bars (distinguishable) outcomes are not equally likely (assuming "randomly" means "uniformly and independent" as it usually does), which makes it a hard way to answer the probability questions here.

Comment: @Ned: you are totally right ! I answered too hurriedly.. I amended my answer according to possible interpretation of the random process of room occupation.

Answer (score 2):

a) $\binom93*2^6=5376$

b) $\binom93*\binom63=1680$

c) $\binom94*\binom53=1260$